# Extension of XSD Enumerations

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a collection of XSD files with definitions of some datatypes. There is one `simpleType Users` which contains an enumeration of some values.
Now I need to create a own type based on this one. I have to restrict the possible values and I have to add one additional value. I am not allowed to change the original base XSD definition.

```
   <xsd:simpleType name="Users">
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:enumeration value="Admin" />
         <xsd:enumeration value="Reader" />
         <xsd:enumeration value="Writer" />
         <xsd:enumeration value="Supervisor" />
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
```

How to restrict that only `Admin, Reader and Writer` are useable and additionally `LegalOffice` is a possible value?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Usually you would use a schematron to evaluate and restrict content, but this valuating of the data  eg by using regular expression but not type type of data, eg XSLT 2.0 or higher or true schematrons

Comment: You need to create your own schema and redefine the element.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_redefine.asp